# Issue with vertical dividers on horizontal UL

Tags: html, css

I tried to add a vertical divider on my nav bar, but I now have a divider at the beginning of the first list item that I can't get rid of. I just want it to look like this: HOME | CONTACT

[Here](http://www.dbayliss.com) is the website to view the problem. Thank you in advance :)

```css
#nav ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;

}

#nav li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size:20px;
 
}

#nav li:before {
content: " | ";
}

#nav li:first-child:before {
content: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav"> <!-- nav open -->

 <ul> <!-- ul open -->
  <li><a class="menu" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="menu" href="https://dbayliss.typeform.com/to/Jm3wF9">Contact</a></li>
    
</ul> <!-- ul close -->

</div> <!-- nav close -->
```

Comment: try changing the `#nav li` from `display:inline` to `display:inline-block`

Comment: Use `#nav li:not(:first-child):before { content: " | "; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**:first-child**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) is defined as:

`The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.`

Bu you have an `a` tag as the first element in the parent `ul` before your `li` (which is invalid HTML by the way).

You (should) can remove it and your current code would work:

[**:FIRST-CHILD EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zt6vw4vk/2/)

Or you can use `nth-of-type()` instead:

```
#nav li:nth-of-type(1):before {
   content: none;
}
```

[**NTH_OF_TYPE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zt6vw4vk/1/)

**OR**

Use the `border` property:

```
#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0 8px;

}

#nav li:last-child{
    border: none;
}
```

[**BORDER EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zt6vw4vk/)

Comment: Thanks that fixes the issue of there being a divider before the first list item, however the divider is now the same height as the div they are within. Is there any way to adjust the height of the border?

Comment: @WebNoob ah yeah, you can't adjust the height, I found a fix for your current code, updated my post

Comment: Ah ha you've done it. Thanks man :) Really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Have a great day!

Comment: @WebNoob no problem. Glad to help. You too. Can you check this off as resolved?